# Split string remove special characters and only write the last string of the same in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following xmlhttp.responseText:

```
var Text = "FS2Crew A320 Checklist_1""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_1""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_10""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_11""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_12""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_13""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_14""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_2""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_3""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_4""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_5""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_6""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_7""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_8""FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_9""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_1""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_2""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_3""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_4""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_5""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_6""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_7""FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_8""VFR-Ffdfdfdlight-Planner-Dax_1""VFR-Ffdfdfdlight-Planner-Dax_2"
```

As a result, I would like a array with the following:

```
result = [FS2Crew A320 Checklist~1, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual~14, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual~8, VFR-Ffdfdfdlight-Planner-Dax~2]
```

I would like to list a string in an array without the character (") and write the number of occurrences with the character (~) at the end.

The character (~) is not mandatory, it should only be one that does not appear in a file name

Sorry for my horrible english.

Comment: As a result? ... of what? I take it you're still composing your question. Will be back when you're done.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the result in valid JavaScript syntax. `result[] = ` would never work. `result = [ ... ]` would work. If you wanted an array of strings, each string should be surrounded by quote marks. It's generally better to compose your question as a whole, then post it. You can use the Preview to see what the question will look like, and Stack Overflow will save drafts, but I suggest finding a Markdown editor that you can use offline. Please do read [ask] and make sure you hit the right notes with your question.

Comment: As the result of a javascript function.
However, editing the string is enough for me

Comment: I'm still not sure your original string or resulting array are valid, nor do they seem to match up. But what are the rules you are using to turn the string into an array? What special character(s) would you use to delimit?

Comment: I want to remove the (") characters

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the characters and create an array.

Here is the function:

```js
    function getFiles(){
        var path = '/images';
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        src='files.php'
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            
                    var list = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    var arrStr = list.split(/[""][""]/);
                    var arrayLength = arrStr.length;
                    
                    arrStr.forEach(function (item) {
                        filename = item.replace('"', '')
                        console.log(filename);
                    });
                }
                else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                    alert('There was an error 400');
                }
                else {
                    alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "filelist.txt", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Thats the result:

```
result: [FS2Crew A320 Checklist_1, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_1, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_10, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_11, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_12, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_13, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_14, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_2, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_3, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_4, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_5, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_6, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_7, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_8, FS2Crew Flight Crew A320 Main Ops Manual_9, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_1, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_2, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_3, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_4, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_5, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_6, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_7, FS2Crew Pushback Express Main Ops Manual_8, VFR-Ffdfdfdlight-Planner-Dax_1, VFR-Ffdfdfdlight-Planner-Dax_2]
```